# Is there a better readable way to write this if statement chain?

Tags: c++11, readability, code-readability

I have the following code:

```
Creature::cancelWalk()
{
    Player* player = getPlayer();

    if (!player) {
        if (getMonster() && getMonster()->getMaster() && getMonster()->getMaster()->getPlayer()) {
            player = getMonster()->getMaster()->getPlayer();
        }
    }

    if (player) {
        player->sendCancelMessage(ret);
        player->sendCancelWalk();
    }
}
```

After a brief analysis, it's easy to understand I want to achieve something simple:

If the `creature` is the `player` itself, then `sendCancelMessage` and `sendCancelWalk`. Else, if the `creature` is a `monster` that also has a master that is a `player`, send the same stuff to the client.

Is there a better way to write this code **without** adding other methods on `Monster`, `Creature` and `Player` classes?

`Monster` and `Player` both are "siblings" deriving from `Creature`.

Comment: Assuming that consecutive calls to `getMonster()->getMaster()->getPlayer()` can't return different values, you don't have to check its value in the `if` statement.

Comment: Looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the various functions don't have different effects on multiple calls, try introducing some temporaries.

```
Player* player = getPlayer();

if (!player)
{
    Monster monster = getMonster();
    if (monster)
    {
        Master *master = monster->getMaster();
        if (master) player = master->getPlayer()) {
    }
}

if (player) {
    player->sendCancelMessage(ret);
    player->sendCancelWalk();
}
```

Beyond that, you might want to look more carefully at your design.   If you have lots of nested pointers that you need to sequentially check for NULL before dereferencing, it might be worth specifying and enforcing invariants that the pointers are not NULL  (which means only construct parent objects if all the component parts can be created, and never construct objects if they can only be partially constructed).

For example, if we assume that `getMonster()` returns non-NULL which guarantees that `getMaster()` and `getPlayer()` also don't return NULL ....

```
Player* player = getPlayer();

if (!player)
{
    player = getMonster()->getMaster()->getPlayer());
}

if (player)
{
    player->sendCancelMessage(ret);
    player->sendCancelWalk();
}
```

Comment: You've assumed that non-NULL getMonster() implies non-NULL getMaster() and getPlayer() but your code doesn't do a null check on getMonster(). Moreover it was specified in the question that a monster might not have any master and that master might not be a player.

Comment: You missed my point, pkubik, which is to redesign to avoid the need for NULL checks.     I'll tweak the words to spell it out.